# Collection rendering issue with existing collection in google firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a google firebase collection names Profiles. I want to access that collection in my react native application. I am calling the correct method to get the collection so that I can add a new document but it keep getting an error saying some thing regarding the collection is undefined and I have no idea why.

This is only happening when I try to access the Profiles collection...

code:

```
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth"
import { db } from '../../firebase'

import { addDoc, collection, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/database'

const CreateProfileScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const auth = getAuth()

  const collectionRef = collection(db, 'Profiles')

  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState()
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState()
  const [city, SetCity] = useState()
  const [state, setState] = useState()
  const [country, setCountry] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    if(auth.currentUser === null){
      navigation.navigate('LoginStack')
    }
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(firstName)
  }, [firstName])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(lastName)
  }, [lastName])
```

[image: The error that I am getting]

[image: The list of collection in my database]

Answer (score 0):

Your import line is incorrect:

```
import { addDoc, collection, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/database'
```

You don't want to use firebase/database.  That is for Realtime Database, which is a different database product than Firestore.  Please review the examples in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) carefully.  You will want to use firebase/firestore intead.

```
import { addDoc, collection, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore'
```